# Multiple Regular expression in one line

Tags: python, regex, data-science, data-analysis

```
list_num=['AYSGS11458630001111252','1234567','LUPUP003164311E0111644','ABCGFD','AFC123A']
```

For the above list_num i wanted to write RE which gives out put as below.

**Expected output**

```
AYSGS11458630001111252
none
LUPUP003164311E0111644
none
none
```

Output should be two items in list

I have written online please correct and suggest me.

```
re.match((r"^(([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{17})|([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}))$", list_num)
```

Comment: _For the above list_num i wanted to write RE which gets both of them._ Gets both what? What is your question?

Comment: You cant just show two examples of some seemingly random string and expect people to give you the perfect answer to what you need. You will need to explain how these two strings come to be and what they are used for. You need to provide some context. Otherwise something like `r'(.*)^` would be a perfectly valid answer to your question. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AMC i have corrected my ask

Comment: can you maybe describe in text form, what kind of pattern you want to match?

Comment: one option 5 Capital Alphabets and 17 numeric numbers. second option 5 Capital Alphabets and 9 numeric numbers and 1 Capital Alphabet and 7 numeric numbers. if one of them matches also i want to display that serial number @user8408080

Comment: @GuruS That explanation should be added to your post, and be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Well then your regex should be fine, with some minor mistakes. It should be: `re.match(r"^(([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{17})$|^([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}))$", list_num)`. But you cant match a list; which might be the problem you're having

Answer (score 0):

`re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)` is defined as `return
re.compile(pattern, flags).match(string)` It cannot handle a list of
strings instead of a string, but that's easy enough to fix with a loop.
But since we're going to be running the same expression multiple times,
it's better to compile it once, rather than repeatedly inside the loop.

This is what I would do:

```
import re
list_num=['AYSGS11458630001111252','1234567','LUPUP003164311E0111644','ABCGFD','AFC123A']

pattern = r"^(([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{17})|([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}))$"
compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

for m in map(compiled_pattern.match, list_num):
    #you could also use pattern.fullmatch, and not enclose your pattern with ^ and $
    if m is not None:
        print(m.string)
    else:
        print(m)
## shows:
##AYSGS11458630001111252
##None
##LUPUP003164311E0111644
##None
##None
```

Or else this:

```
x = [m.string if isinstance(m, re.Match) else m
     for m in map(compiled_pattern.match, list_num)]
print (x)
#['AYSGS11458630001111252', None, 'LUPUP003164311E0111644', None, None]

'or even this:'
def multi_match(pattern, seq):
    compiled_pattern=re.compile(pattern)
    return [m.string if isinstance(m, re.Match) else m
            for m in map(compiled_pattern.match, list_num)]

print(multi_match(pattern, list_num))
#['AYSGS11458630001111252', None, 'LUPUP003164311E0111644', None, None]
```

Or if index positions do not need to be preserved, something like:

```
def filter_match(pattern, seq):
    compiled_pattern=re.compile(pattern)
    return list(filter(
        lambda line: compiled_pattern.match(line) is not None,
        list_num))

print(filter_match(pattern, list_num))
#['AYSGS11458630001111252', 'LUPUP003164311E0111644']
```